# Send verification email before logging in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

This is the code that i'm practicing in to create a new user. I can receive the email verification and confirm it however, the site will still logged me in even if I have not yet confirmed my email yet.

```
try{

      const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
      await user.sendEmailVerification();
      await handleUserProfile(user, { displayName});

      this.setState({
        ...initialSate
      });

     }catch(err){
       console.log(err);
     }
  }
```

This is the handleUserProfile in another js file.

```
export const handleUserProfile = async (userAuth, additionalData) => {
    if (!userAuth) return;
    const {uid} = userAuth;

    const userRef = firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`);
        
    //create new user
    const snapshot = await userRef.get();
    if (!snapshot.exists){
        const { displayName, email} = userAuth;
        const timestamp = new Date();
        //if the user exist  does not exist
        try{
            await userRef.set({
                displayName,
                email,
                createdDate: timestamp,
                ...additionalData
            });

        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    return userRef;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything is explained in the firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth).
There you have the corresponding code snippets to try.
You would need to narrow down your question with some of this trials.
Even you have the chance to check if user opens the link from a differenc device from which waas signed up.

I think this is the snippet you might need:

```
// Confirm the link is a sign-in with email link.
if (firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(window.location.href)) {
  // Additional state parameters can also be passed via URL.
  // This can be used to continue the user's intended action before triggering
  // the sign-in operation.
  // Get the email if available. This should be available if the user completes
  // the flow on the same device where they started it.
  var email = window.localStorage.getItem('emailForSignIn');
  if (!email) {
    // User opened the link on a different device. To prevent session fixation
    // attacks, ask the user to provide the associated email again. For example:
    email = window.prompt('Please provide your email for confirmation');
  }
  // The client SDK will parse the code from the link for you.
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink(email, window.location.href)
    .then((result) => {
      // Clear email from storage.
      window.localStorage.removeItem('emailForSignIn');
      // You can access the new user via result.user
      // Additional user info profile not available via:
      // result.additionalUserInfo.profile == null
      // You can check if the user is new or existing:
      // result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Some error occurred, you can inspect the code: error.code
      // Common errors could be invalid email and invalid or expired OTPs.
    });
}
```

Comment: I'll check this out. Thank you

Comment: You may clarify that your answer actually implies another way of authenticating a user, i.e. by using Email Link. While it is a solution to verify the email of a user, it does not exactly answers to the OP question, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

> The site will still logged me in even if I have not yet confirmed my
> email yet.

Yes this is how it is implemented in Firebase: there is nothing, out of the box, that prevents a user with a non-verified email to authenticate to your app.

You should manage that yourself, by:

1. Checking the email is verified in the back-end security rules (Firestore, Cloud Storage, etc..). For example with a function like:

---

```
function isVerifiedEmailUser() {
    return request.auth.token.email_verified == true;
}
```

---

2. Possibly redirect and logout the user from your app if his/her email is not verified. For example, right after signing-up, as follows:

---

```
try {

       const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
       await user.sendEmailVerification();
      
       if (user.emailVerified) {
             // display the content, redirect to another page, etc...
       } else {
            auth.signOut();   // Maybe call that after showing an error message
       }

     } catch(err){
         console.log(err);
     }
  }
```

plus, potentially, something similar with `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` and `onAuthStateChanged()`.